# Issue with datetimepicker field

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker

I have some issue with datetimepicker field, I'm using [bootstrap datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker),
The data from DB gives me for e.g : **2019-12-14 15:23:00**
But the field is showing : **2014-12-20 15:23:00** (about 6 days difference)

I've looked at the code source and the field has **2014-12-14T15:23:00Z** as value...

Value into value attribute
[image]

Value shown by datetimepicker field

[image]

```
$('.dateDebut').datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm',

                minDate: moment(),
                defaultDate: moment(),

                sideBySide: true,
                ignoreReadonly: true,
                // as Bootstrap 4 is not using Glyphicons anymore
                icons: {
                    time: 'fa fa-clock-o',
                    date: 'fa fa-calendar',
                    up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
                    down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
                    previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
                    next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
                    today: 'fa fa-check',
                    clear: 'fa fa-trash',
                    close: 'fa fa-times'
                }
            });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not only changing the date but year also (by looking at both the images you posted). Can you share some relevant code to reproduce this issue at our end so that we can take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, I've just added the code which generate the datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

You can set your datepicker value by Jquery:

```
$('.datedebut').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' ,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true ,
});
$('.datedebut').datepicker('setDate', '2014-12-20');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be used the below code to set the date. You need to update the format of displaying the date

```js
function BindDatePicker() {
  var dateNow = new Date();

  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm',
    weekStart: 1,
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "6,0",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
  });
  $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", dateNow);
});
}
```

> Otherwise you can use pickadate JS

```
function BindDatePicker() {
var dateNow = new Date();
$('.datePicker').each(function () {
    var $input = $(this).pickadate({
        today: '',
        clear: '',
        close: 'Cancel',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        format: 'd mmm, yyyy',
    })
    var picker = $input.pickadate('picker')
    picker.set('select', dateNow)
});
```

}

Comment: Thanks but I need absolutely to edit also the hour and minutes..

Comment: Can you explain more what is the exact problem you are facing?